# Block UI using jquery while request is processing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My requirement is to block the ui while the request is in process,and unblock the ui when the processing is completed. I am using jQuery blockui plugin for this. 
I am not getting how to use this so that the ui will be blocked only when the request is in process.
I don't want the user to click on screen to unblock the UI. 
UI should get blocked when the page started loading and should get unblocked when the page is completely loaded.
Request is not an ajax request.
Please give some suggestions.

Comment: refer http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos for demo of blockUi

Comment: Yes, I have already seen this link, but they are unblocking the ui either by setting timeout or ob button click. My requirement is , ui should get unblocked automatically when the request is processed completely or the page is loaded completely.

Comment: what is the request you are processing and how do you know that the request is complete?

Comment: It is simply when the page is loaded completely

Answer (score 0):

i usually put a leyer on top of the ui part/entire screen, with partial trasparency and a message

```
function camoOn(){
    $("#camoflager").show();
}

function camoOff(){
        $("#camoflager").hide(); 
}
```

Comment: But on which events I have to call these methods?

Comment: depend on your code, but call the on if you want to hide it, for example at the function where you start to load stuffs with ajax, or process something, and off if you finished,

Comment: also this two is not jquery built in stuff, the  $.blockUI(); one is the official

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
 <script>

$(document).load(function(){
   $.blockUI();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
      $.unblockUI();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it is not working. Below code is working to block the UI, but still I am not able to understand on which event I should unblock the UI.                                 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.blockUI();
});
</script>

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with this